# Automatic update of pivot table- EXCEL

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

[Image error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lU6oe.jpg)

Dears;

I find a error in bellow code in depurator the VBA point this:

**Pivot_Sheet.PivotTables(PivotName). _
ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=NewRange)**

The code below:

```
Sub UpdatePivotTableRange()

Dim Data_Sheet As Worksheet
Dim Pivot_Sheet As Worksheet
Dim StartPoint As Range
Dim DataRange As Range
Dim PivotName As String
Dim NewRange As String
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim lastRow As Long

'Set Pivot Table & Source Worksheet
Set Data_Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BASE")
Set Pivot_Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TABELA")

'Enter in Pivot Table Name
PivotName = "Tabela dinâmica3"

'Defining Staring Point & Dynamic Range
Data_Sheet.Activate
Set StartPoint = Data_Sheet.Range("A1")
LastCol = StartPoint.End(xlToRight).Column
DownCell = StartPoint.End(xlDown).Row
Set DataRange = Data_Sheet.Range(StartPoint, Cells(DownCell, LastCol))

NewRange = Data_Sheet.Name & "!" & DataRange.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)


'Change Pivot Table Data Source Range Address

 

Pivot_Sheet.PivotTables(PivotName). _
ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=NewRange)

 'Ensure Pivot Table is Refreshed
Pivot_Sheet.PivotTables(PivotName).RefreshTable

'Complete Message
Pivot_Sheet.Activate
MsgBox "Relatório " & PivotName & " foi atualizado. Aperte OK."

      
End Sub
```

Comment: [Any of these help?](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB907GB907&ei=SELqX4qvO8eVgQaE8ZKICA&q=vba+runtime+error+5+pivottable&oq=vba+runtime+error+5+pivottable&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIGCAAQDRAeMggIABAIEA0QHjoHCAAQRxCwA1Cy9gJYsvYCYMH4AmgBcAJ4AIABV4gBV5IBATGYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6yAEHwAEB&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwiK87ePxPHtAhXHSsAKHYS4BIEQ4dUDCA0&uact=5)

Comment: I will take a look.....